# Ruby on rails, html/script for loop

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am using [this file upload example for Ruby on Rails](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails-paperclip-example).I have the following template to display files available for downloading:

```
  <script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
      {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
        <tr class="template-download fade">          
           
          <td class="name">
           <a href="{%=file.url%}" download="{%=file.name%}">{%=file.name%}</a>
          </td>            
          <td class="File_info">
            <a href="{%=file.url_file_info%}" class= "btn btn-mini btn-info">File Info</a>       
          </td>
          <td class="Hist">
          <a href="{%=file.url_hist_image%}" class= "btn btn-mini btn-info">Hist</a>        
          </td>   
         
    
          <td class="delete">
            <button class="btn btn-mini btn-danger" data-type="{%=file.delete_type%}" data-url="{%=file.delete_url%}"> 
              <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>              
            </button>
            <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1">
          </td>
        </tr>
        {% } %}
    </script>
```

I have never seen such a strange for loop:
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
blabla
{% } %}

What does those brackets mean ( {%} {%} ) ? And is there an if loop for such html/script templates (just an analog to for loop)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

These blocks are client-side templates, Have a look at the documentation [Here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl)

Comment: of if i want to include an if-loop into a for-loop, I have just to write if (..){blabla} without those blocks?